# Multiple errors when importing Gradle project

Tags: java, gradle

I wanted to read the source code of a java project, so I cloned the project into a directory, and opened it in VSCode. The project used gradle as a dependency manager. None of the dependencies were downloaded, so I ran

`gradle --refresh-dependencies`

This seemed to work in getting everything setup, but there were many different errors such as

`Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method reload() from the type FastRegistry`

This error seemed to be the most common, but VSCode reports 2000 errors. I should mention that this project is a Minecraft Mod, so there may be some conflict with the source code and the mapped class names. I am still a beginner at this kind of stuff, so hopefully there is a simple solution. Here is a link to the project: https://github.com/PorkStudios/FarPlaneTwo/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After asking the project owner about this, I found that this project uses lombok annotations. Because of the weirdly formatted annotations, everything was thrown off.

To fix this for VSCode, which does not support these annotations by default, install the extensions for it.

In addition to this, if you have already loaded the project, you will need to clean the workspace.